# Why is javascript not passing along my variable to the next function?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In my function make_graph I'm using highcharts to create a graph and then using getSVG to convert it into an svg and save it as the variable svg_graph. I then return svg_graph to another function. In the original function that creates svg_graph, when I console.log(svg_graph) the console shows the svg. But, when the second function receives svg_graph and console.log's it there, it shows as undefined. Why? I should mention that getSVG returns a string of at a maximum of 900000 chars in length.

Here is the code where I create the svg (I removed the highcharts code to make this more readable)

```
function make_graph() {
    var svg_graph = chart.getSVG();
    console.log('Hey in function'+svg_graph); //this shows in console 
    return svg_graph;
}
```

Here is the code where is gets returned

```
var svg = make_graph();
console.log(svg); // shows as undefined???
```

Comment: Well, clearly `chart.getSVG()` returns .... wait for it ..... `undefined` ?

Comment: Assuming `chart.getSVG()` does not return `undefined` (try logging it without `'Hey in function'`) then it's impossible for `var svg = make_graph()` to be `undefined`.

Comment: What does `console.log('Hey in function'+svg_graph);` show? Are you saying it does show the correct `svg_graph` value as well as the "Hey..." string?

Comment: It works just fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rLfsm2t5/**

Comment: are you running that second snippet of code in the developer tools console or is that code in your page?

Comment: You may be missing something...Check properly your linked libraries links..!

Comment: if you run that second piece of code in the developer tools console, the last value shown will be *undefined* - but that's the value returned by `console.log` - check your console output carefully

Comment: 900000 chars is two zeros over 9000!!! , vegeta. Sorry.

Comment: 'chart.getSVG()' does not returrn undefined. The 'console.log('Hey in...)' returns the correct svg string. I also recently loged the 'typeof(svg_graph)' and that gave me string so it's definitely not undefined. However, for some reason svg is undefined once it gets passed to the second function. This is all running in a js file that makes ajax call to php.